# C# Asp.net string values HttpRequestHeader

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-request-parameters

I send data to the API via `HttpRequestHeader` (post)
The server response is:

```
code1=7ea12f&code2=3867&code3=123&code4=104
```

I need to string each value to view them in separate label.

```
label1.text = code1;
label2.text = code2;
label3.text = code3;
label4.text = code4;
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Have you tried HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var nameValueCollection = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("code1=7ea12f&code2=3867&code3=123&code4=104");

label1.text = nameValueCollection["code1"];
label2.text = nameValueCollection["code2"];
label3.text = nameValueCollection["code3"];
label4.text = nameValueCollection["code4"];
```